# Prove two functions are solution of linear homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two functions, $y_1=x^2$ and $y_2=x^2ln(x)$. How can I prove that both are solutions of the linear homogeneous equation $x^3y'''-2xy'+4y=0$?

All I have right now is that by the superposition principle, the following linear combination is also a solution: 
$$
y=c_1x^2+c_2x^2ln(x)
$$

But I'm not sure where to go from here, and the book I'm reading (Morris Tenenbaum/Harry Pollard) doesn't give similar examples. What would be the process for proving this type of exercises? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Plug the solution in the DE.. For $x^2$ you get  $x^30-2x(2x)+4x^2=0$

Comment: This is an Euler-Cauchy equation with characteristic polynomial $$0=m(m-1)(m-2)-2m+4=(m-2)(m^2-m-2)=(m-2)^2(m+1)$$ giving basis solutions $x^{-1},x^2,x^2\ln x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y_1$ is a solution of the differential equation:
$$x^3y'''-2xy'+4y=0$$
Then you have
$$x^3y_1'''-2xy_1'+4y_1=0$$
$$x^3.0-2x(2x)+4x^2=0$$
Which is true. So $x^2$ is a solution of the DE.
Do the same for $y_2=x^2 \ln x$
$$x^3y_2'''-2xy_2'+4y_2=0$$

Comment: I see, so you are obtaining from $y$ its derivatives, $y'$, $y''$ and $y'''$, then plugging all these into the equation. Did I get you right? In which case, what would be the importance of it being an homogeneous linear equation?

Comment: @FernandoGómez yes that's exactly that. Plug the solution in the differential equation and see if the equality holds. Linearity is important since for these equations you can apply the principle of superposition.

Comment: Thanks, got the solution now for both!

Comment: you're welcomed @FernandoGómez